# How to use process.env on apollo-client?

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, apollo-client

I have a Next.js app and using apollo-client for GraphCMS.

Once I have set environment variables for URI and token on ApolloClient object, GraphQL query does not work and return. Actually, I can get data from GraphCMS. The problem is only for mutations.

Here is the .env file:

```
GRAPHCMS_ENDPOINT=https://api-some-thing.graphcms.com/v2/sd3s
GRAPHCMS_TOKEN=tsd89asd24jnNM
```

And here is apollo-client.js:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: process.env.GRAPHCMS_ENDPOINT,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  headers: {
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${process.env.GRAPHCMS_TOKEN}`
  }
});

export default client;
```

If I set URI and token as string I mean not using process.env, everything works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you need the environment variables in the browser you need to prefix them with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`. See [NextJS environment variables aren't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63257107/nextjs-environment-variables-arent-working).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working now.